# How to wait until only one row shows from autocomplete entry

Tags: cypress

I am running Cypress against a PHP site that I cannot alter in any way.

It has an autocomplete input field that sends a stream of XHR calls to the server.

The results fill a table in which each row has a button that can be clicked.

I need to wait until there is just one row, then click its button.

```
cy.get('#dataTables_clients_filter > label > .form-control').type(client).then(() => {
  cy.get('table#dataTables_clients > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(6) > i').click();
}
```

The result of the above is an error `cy.click() can only be called on a single element. Your subject contained 100 elements.`

The number of XHR calls varies depending on the value of client.

The difficulty arises from this: as `theInput.type(client)` inserts a letter at a time, the page sends a new XHR for each one. This means that initially, there will be a long list of rows one of which will always contain 'client'. As more and more letters are processed, the list gets shorter, ending eventually with just one row.

How can I wait until any one of the following to be true?

- `tbody > tr:nth-child(0) > td:nth-child(4)` equals `client`
- no more XHR calls are being sent
- the length of the tables array of rows is equal to 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cy.waitUntil(() => {
  return cy.get('@Clientes').eq(0).children().eq(4).then(($cl) => {
    const res = Boolean($cl[0].innerText === client);
    return res;
  });
}, {
  errorMsg: 'Autocomplete failed to find client',
  timeout: 15000,
  interval: 500
});
```

This!  [Add the Cypress waiting power to virtually everything](https://github.com/NoriSte/cypress-wait-until).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to just assure all 3 are valid. You could do that like this:

```js
// wait until the XHR call is done:
cy.server()
cy.route('/api-call/which/should/be/finished').as('xhr')
cy.wait('@xhr') // will wait until xhr has appeared.
// Be sure that "tbody > tr:nth-child(0) > td:nth-child(4) equals 'client'"
cy.get('tbody')
  .contains('td', 'client') // will search for a td with 'client' in it.
// The length of the tables array of rows is equal to 1
cy.get('tbody')
  .find('tr') // this will be valid if there is at least 1 row.
```

Comment: That looks ok superficially, but ... as theInput.type(client) inserts a letter at a time, the page sends a new XHR for each one.  This means that initially, there will be a long list of rows one of which one will always contain 'client'.  As more and more letters are processed, the list gets shorter, ending eventually with just one row.  So, all three of your tests will succeed with the first letter sent.  Meanwhile, I do appreciate your interest in helping. Thanks.

Comment: check, what is the behaviour you expect then? Because if that assertion is true for every input, you don't even need to execute it.

Comment: I have listed three conditions.  Any one of them solves my problem. Not one of your 3 suggestions give the necessary result.

Comment: ah, check, so one of the three assertions should be true? That is gonna be interesting since Cypress can't check if there are no XHR-calls anymore. It can only check for a specified XHR call.

Comment: Thanks for contributing some mutual mulling. :-)